# Is there a maximum number of x-Axis items in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using HighCharts to make a 3 level drilldown.

When I use over 50 items at the second level, the item text no longer displays on the left. Click on the first item (Parent 1) and then you will see the second level and what is not displaying.

Is this due to the amount of JSON data I am using?

Here is the code I am using for the chart

```
let options = {
chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    events: {
        drilldown: function (e) {
            if (e.seriesOptions) {
                e.seriesOptions.hiddenValue = e.point.options.hiddenValue;
            }
        }
  }
},
title: {
    text: 'Overall Status'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
        style: {
            fontSize: '15px'
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    title:{
            text: "Percentage Complete"
        },
    labels: {
        style: {
            fontSize: '15px'
        }
    }
},

legend: {
    enabled: false
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontSize: '20px'
            }
        },
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    let seriesOptions = this.series && this.series.options;
                    let hiddenValue = seriesOptions && seriesOptions.hiddenValue;
                    if(this.options && this.options.url) {
                        location.href = this.options.url + '?id=' + hiddenValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Status',
    colorByPoint: true
}],
drilldown: {
}
};
```

I have a fiddle here that has the JSON data. 
    https://jsfiddle.net/mark2017/yb3y9dt9/

Comment: Yes, it is due to the amount of space. IIRC, the bars will all display, but the labels won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that the first drilldown does not start from 0 value, instead it starts from 10 - like it would count in all the values from the top level series. It is a bug which was already reported on github: [Drilldown to more than 50 - skip categories name](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5857)

Setting `cropTreshold` to a number bigger than the number of all your points seems to work in your case - it must be set for all series, e.g. in `plotOptions.series`

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    cropThreshold: 2000,
    borderWidth: 0,
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/hfpofx28/

Comment: Thanks for this, I have tried the change and yes, the names now display, but still not showing more than 50 items ?

Comment: By items, you mean labels or columns? If labels collide some of them will be hidden - to overcome this set labels.step = 1 - if you mean data labels, you need to set allowOverlap to true. https://jsfiddle.net/hfpofx28/1/