# R Highcharter - X-axis names turning to index in graph

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have a couple column graphs in Highcharter that allow drill down. I have noticed that depending on how big the column drill down is, highcharter switches from showing the correct x-axis names to index. Is there a way I can make sure it will always show the x-axis name?

Below is an example code that shows a scenario where it displays correctly and where it doesn't. Only change is the size of the data set (from 400 to 50).

```
library (highcharter)

rm(list=ls())

#### CASE 1 - X AXIS NAMES NOT SHOWING IN DRILLDOWN ####

h <- 0
Case1Num <- c()
for(i in 1:400){
  h <- h + .02
  Case1Num[i] <- h
}

Case1Name <- c()
for(i in 1:400){
  Case1Name[i] <- paste0("test",i)
}

Case1Group <- c()
for(i in 1:400){
  Case1Group[i] <- paste0("group1")
}

Case1 <- data.frame(Case1Name,Case1Num,Case1Group)

Lvl1 <- aggregate(Case1$Case1Num, by = list(Case1$Case1Group),FUN=sum)
Lvl1df <- data_frame(name = Lvl1$Group.1, y = Lvl1$x, drilldown = tolower((paste(name))))

dfLvl2 <- arrange(data_frame(name = Case1$Case1Name,value = Case1$Case1Num),desc(value))

hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column", zoomType = "x") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category", labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "1.1vh"))) %>%
  hc_yAxis(gridLineWidth = 0, labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "1.1vh"))) %>%
  hc_add_series(data=Lvl1df, color = "#D20000") %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%

  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list(
      list(id = "group1", data = list_parse2(dfLvl2))
    )
  )

hc

#### CASE 2 - X AXIS NAMES SHOWING CORRECTLY IN DRILLDOWN ####

h <- 0
Case2Num <- c()
for(i in 1:50){
  h <- h + .02
  Case2Num[i] <- h
}

Case2Name <- c()
for(i in 1:50){
  Case2Name[i] <- paste0("test",i)
}

Case2Group <- c()
for(i in 1:50){
  Case2Group[i] <- paste0("group1")
}

Case2 <- data.frame(Case2Name,Case2Num,Case2Group)

Lvl1 <- aggregate(Case2$Case2Num, by = list(Case2$Case2Group),FUN=sum)
Lvl1df <- data_frame(name = Lvl1$Group.1, y = Lvl1$x, drilldown = tolower((paste(name))))

dfLvl2 <- arrange(data_frame(name = Case2$Case2Name,value = Case2$Case2Num),desc(value))

hc2 <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column", zoomType = "x") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category", labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "1.1vh"))) %>%
  hc_yAxis(gridLineWidth = 0, labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "1.1vh"))) %>%
  hc_add_series(data=Lvl1df, color = "#D20000") %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%

  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list(
      list(id = "group1", data = list_parse2(dfLvl2))
    )
  )

hc2
```

Comment: what version of R and highcharter package do you use. I get the same behavior for both cases you provided (a bar) with "group1" name and "Series1" title in legend below

Comment: HI @Katia, The top level graph is correct, but when you click on the bar to do a drilldown, one shows 1,2,3,4,5... on the x axis while the correct one shows test1, test2, test3, etc... Are you able to see test# for both cases? I am using R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) and highcharter_0.5.0

Comment: Ah, now I see. I suspect that this might be due to the fact that in case of 50 observations it is able to fit a whole word to and when you have 3 digits for each label id does not fit into the margins. Setting up larger margins might help, but I first need to try.

Comment: It looks like any number over 50 (even 51) causes it to switch to index...so my assumption that the name is too long is wrong. It looks like it is a bug in the package.

Comment: This bug already has been reported. See:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378342/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-x-axis-items-in-highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378342/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-x-axis-items-in-highcharts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue was solved in the github thread.

adding  `cropThreshold = 1000` to `hc_plotOptions` solves the trick. It is normally set at default to `50` which is why the above was seen for anything greater.

```
hc2 <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column", zoomType = "x") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category", labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "1.1vh"))) %>%
  hc_yAxis(gridLineWidth = 0, labels = list(style = list(fontSize = "1.1vh"))) %>%
  hc_add_series(data=Lvl1df, color = "#D20000") %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(
                 cropThreshold = 1000,
                 stacking = "normal")) %>%

  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = list(
      list(id = "group1", data = list_parse2(dfLvl2))
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an open issue with Highcharts. Not just in R but in javascript as well.
This issue was reported here:

> https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5857